# MySQL transformation from location list to route

Tags: mysql, sql, bigdata

I got the following database layout:

```
+-----------+------------------+-----------+
| VehicleId |       Date       |  Address  |
+-----------+------------------+-----------+
| ABC123    | 16.11.2016 12:00 | Address 1 |
| ABC123    | 16.11.2016 12:01 | Address 1 |
| ABC123    | 16.11.2016 12:02 | Address 1 |
| ABC123    | 16.11.2016 12:03 | Address 1 |
| ABC123    | 16.11.2016 12:04 | Address 1 |
| ABC123    | 16.11.2016 13:01 | Address 2 |
| …         |                  |           |
| ABC123    | 16.11.2016 14:23 | Address 3 |
| ABC123    | 16.11.2016 14:24 | Address 3 |
| ABC123    | 16.11.2016 14:39 | Address 4 |
| …         |                  |           |
| XYZ456    | 16.11.2016 12:00 | Address x |
| XYZ456    | 16.11.2016 12:01 | Address x |
| XYZ456    | 16.11.2016 12:02 | Address x |
| XYZ456    | 16.11.2016 14:35 | Address y |
+-----------+------------------+-----------+
```

And i want to transform this into

```
+-----------+------------------+------------------+--------------+------------+
| VehicleId |    StartDate     |     EndDate      | StartAddress | EndAddress |
+-----------+------------------+------------------+--------------+------------+
| ABC123    | 16.11.2016 12:04 | 16.11.2016 13:01 | Address 1    | Address 2  |
| ABC123    | 16.11.2016 14:24 | 16.11.2016 14:39 | Address 3    | Address 4  |
| XYZ456    | 16.11.2016 12:02 | 16.11.2016 14:35 | Address x    | Address y  |
+-----------+------------------+------------------+--------------+------------+
```

I already tried something like this

```
select
  t1.vehicleId,
  t1.address as startingAddress,
  t1.date as startingDate,
  endInformation.address as endAddress,
  endInformation.date as endDate

FROM locations t1

  LEFT JOIN locations endInformation ON endInformation.vehicleId = t1.vehicleId and endInformation.date = 
(select t2.date from locations t2 where vehicleId = t1.vehicleId AND date > t1.date limit 1)

  LEFT JOIN locations previousLocation ON endInformation.vehicleId = t1.vehicleId and endInformation.date = 
(select t2.date from locations t2 where vehicleId = t1.vehicleId AND date < t1.date order by date desc limit 1)

WHERE (endInformation.address NOT LIKE previousLocation.address AND t1.address NOT LIKE endInformation.address)
```

But I am running into performance problems, as we are talking about many different vehicles and around 600.000 rows of location information.

Anyone can help me here? Basically, I want to transform the location information into route details, where a route is generated everytime a location of a vehicle changes.

Comment: This looks like a gaps and islands problem, and MySQL doesn't support row number, making it even more difficult.

Comment: Yep that rownumber thing would make it a Lot easier

Comment: @L93 - There is no date "16.11.2016 12:04" and no Address 2 in the basic data. Can you post a create and some sample data ? and is it possible to add a auto increment field in the basis table to speedup the query?

Comment: Hi Bernd, I added the missing sample data, thanks for the hin! Yes I played around with adding an auto increment column simply called id to speedup the join, but I was not successful at all